# dataset does not support system nullable in crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using vs2012 asp.net mvc and crystal reports v.13.

i have this error when i am trying to export the crystal report

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

at this line

> rd.SetDataSource(cn.Customers.Select(c => new

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.listCustomers = cn.Customers.ToList();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Export()
    {
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/CustomerReport.rpt")));
        rd.SetDataSource(cn.Customers.Select(c => new
        {
            CustomerID = c.CustomerID  ,
            CustomerName = c.CustomerName ,
            CustomerEmail = c.CustomerEmail ,
            CustomerZipCode = c.CustomerZipCode ,
            CustomerCountry = c.CustomerCountry ,
            CustomerCity = c.CustomerCity,
        }).ToList());

        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "CustomerList.pdf");
  }
```

this is the view:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>CustomerID</td>
        <td>CustomerName</td>
        <td>CustomerEmail</td>
        <td>CustomerZipCode</td>
        <td>CustomerCountry</td>
        <td>CustomerCity</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var cust in ViewBag.listCustomers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@cust.CustomerID</td>
            <td>@cust.CustomerName</td>
            <td>@cust.CustomerEmail</td>
            <td>@cust.CustomerZipCode</td>
            <td>@cust.CustomerCountry</td>
            <td>@cust.CustomerCity</td>
        </tr>
    }
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="@Url.Action("Export","Customer")">Export report</a>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand that "cn.Customers.Select" is returning an anonymous type where its attributes have infered types.

Then "rd.SetDataSource" takes that object of that anonymous type and create a DataSet to the ReportDocument.

Once the anonymous type has an infered type that is nullable (because of the attributes of your Customer class), the framework try to create a DataColumn using that nullable type. So you get the error mentioned.

So, you may try to drive the anonymous type to avoid nullable types for its attributes. To do the that, try the following. But since i don't know your Customer class, i will simplify the scenario and assume it has only one property and it is nullable.

```
class Customer { public int? CustomerID; }
```

Then you could try this:

```
rd.SetDataSource(cn.Customers.Select(c => new
{
    CustomerID = c.CustomerID == null ? 0 : c.CustomerID
}).ToList());
```

Do something like that for all of your nullable attributes.

Comment: Use of [null-coalescing-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) : `CustomerID = c.CustomerID??0`

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution , in the generate model class you'll find that your class Costumers have multiple system.nullable fields , like Datetimes , doubles , ...

you need to change all the definitions of your fields from system.nullable to normal

```
Nullable<DateTime> date_exemple;
```

to

```
DateTime date_exemple;
```

hope this will solve your problem and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Nullable fields must be written with value.
For example as shown below.

```
rd.SetDataSource(cn.Customers.Select(c => new
{
    CustomerID = c.CustomerID.Value
}).ToList());
```